# Adding new data into mysql database in Java button

Tags: java, swing, variables, jdbc, final

I want to add new info to my mysql database from my Java GUI.
I have 3 textfields which takes info from user and have 1 checkbutton. I have to add these datas, however I have a query for it.

```
String query="insert into buses (busId,custname,custsurname,custid,seats)
values('"+busId+"','"+textfield_1.getText()+"','"+textfield_2.getText()+
"','"+textfield_3.getText()+"','"+checkbox[1].getName()+"')";
```

When I write it in Java button, compiler give me a error like this `(busId should be final)`
how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you want this text to appear on the button? or you want to execute the code when the user clicks the button?

Comment: yes i want to execute it when user click the button,how???

Comment: Also, consider using a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html), because of [this](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Google Java Swing tutorial. Follow a few simple examples. Than transfer that knowledge to your current problem,

Answer (score 1):

```
compiler give me a error like this(busId should be final)
```

I'm assuming that you're using this variable within an anonymous inner class. All you have to do, as the error suggests, is declare the `busId` to be `final`, e.g.

```
final int busId = 0;
```

Comment: but i take busid from other class with constructor ,can it affect something wrong??

Comment: user select busid in jlist so i cant make it 0...

Comment: @gzml, Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class).

Comment: @gzml, And for better help sooner, please include an [sscce](http://www.sscce.org).